# where does gnome-do store its information

Tags: gnome-do

I want to know where does gnome-do store its information.

(configuration and history info).

http://do.cooperteam.net/release.shtml

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu the configs are by default in this folder

~/.[programname] (`~/.do` or `~/.gnome-do`)

and maybe the history too (or is specified in the config)

edit: If you do not see files starting with a dot (hidden files/directories), you kann press

CTRL + H

in nautilus

Answer (score 0):

Do stores it's state in a couple of places:

`~/.local/share/gnome-do` is where it stores its persistent state - the items you frequently use, and any locally-installed plugins.

It stores confguration in `gconf`, under the `/apps/gnome-do` namespace. You can fiddle around here using `gconf-editor`.